# "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64 error" when migrating from React Navigation 5 to 6 on iOS

Tags: react-native, react-navigation, react-navigation-v6, react-native-screens

I am developing an app with React Native and trying to migrate from React Navigation 5 to 6. For this I have followed the steps that come in the [Upgrading from 5.x](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/upgrading-from-5.x/) guide.

The versions of React and React Native are these:

```
"react": "17.0.2",
"react-native": "0.67.2",
```

I have installed these packages:

```
"@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.2.0",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.8",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.12.0",
"react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
```

After upgrading the packages I ran `pod install` command in `ios` folder.

If I run `npx react-native run-ios --simulator="iPhone 13"` command or I run on a device using Xcode, I get this error:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSSearchBar", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNScreens.a(RNSScreenStackHeaderConfig.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSScreenStackAnimator", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNScreens.a(RNSScreenStack.o)
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_RNSScreenWindowTraits", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in libRNScreens.a(RNSScreen.o)
      objc-class-ref in libRNScreens.a(RNSScreenStack.o)
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

It looks like `libRNScreens.a` is from the `react-native-screens` package.

Do you know how to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to solve the problem in my case has been to downgrade `react-native-screens` library to version 3.11.1. Now it runs without problems.

Answer (score 0):

It might be related to using `use_frameworks!` in Podfile. Try adding the following step to your Podfile:

```
pre_install do |installer|
    installer.pod_targets.each do |pod|
      if pod.name.eql?('RNScreens')
        def pod.build_type
          Pod::BuildType.static_library
        end
      end
    end
  end
```

Details [Here](https://github.com/software-mansion/react-native-screens/issues/842#issuecomment-790498006)

Comment: I tried adding this code in different places in the Podfile, but I get the same error. After Podfile changes should I run something before running the app?

Comment: yes, run pod install command.  `project->ios->pod install`

Comment: I tried downgrading ```react-native-screens``` package to 3.11.1 and it runs without problems. I think I will go in this way, thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

solution is very simple

remove this

Xcode -> Build Settings -> Search Paths -> Library Search Paths -> "$(TOOLCHAINDIR)/usr/lib/swift-5.0/$(PLATFORMNAME)"

Comment: I have Debug and Release parameters with the same value: ```iphoneos/usr/lib/swift "/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/switf/iphoneos" ""```. Should I remove both properties?

Comment: @Jon yes, that's right